# Live Window Resizing is very slow - ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity, compiz

live window resizing is very very slow, if i activate it through compiz config manager.
I searched the web for a while, but found no reason why.
It's obviously an unity/compiz problem.

The question is, is there an easy way to fix this?
Is this also a problem in ubuntu 13.04?

I need this feature for designing responsive websites.

I love Ubuntu, I use it since many years, so i don't want to switch to an other operating system ...

Comment: I can only confirm that this is still a problem in 13.04 :(

Comment: Me too. Seems like resizing with Alt F8 is faster.

Comment: Is this the same as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1039673 ? If so, you should login and acknowledge it as a problem affecting you so that it gets prioritized.

Comment: Still looking for an answer?